# OpenCV: create a square Structuring element for HIT-MISS

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I want a function to create a "square inside a square" structuring element, like:

```
    Mat explicit_kernel = (Mat_<int>(5, 5) <<
                -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                -1, 1, 1, 1, -1,
                -1, 1, 1, 1, -1,
                -1, 1, 1, 1, -1,
                - 1, -1, -1, -1, -1);
```

So I tried to make an ugly loop:

```
Mat generate_kernel(int size)
{
    if (size % 2 == 0)
    {
        printf("Input %i, not even, replaced by %i\n", size, size + 1);
        size++;

    }

    Mat out = Mat::ones(size + 2, size + 2, CV_8S);
    for (int i = 0; i <= size + 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= size + 1; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || i == size - 1)
            {
                out.at<int>(i, j) = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (j == 0 || j == size - 1)
                {
                    out.at<int>(i, j) = -1;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    //Mat out = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(size, size), Point(-1, -1));
    return out;

}
```

But I got an "Violation writting error", and anyway Im looking for an easier want,
The main purpose of the code is to make structuring element inside a loop:
- squares of size 1, size 3 ...
Thanks :)

Comment: This is wrong too: `j <= size + j`.

Comment: Thanks, I modified to            j  <= size + j;           and it was not     i++ but j++          No more violation error

Comment: But now, the generate matrix is just full of -1 , not more 1

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, considering that cv::Mat is a pointer, and creating a sub Matrix

```
Mat generate_kernel(int size)
{
    if (size % 2 == 0)
    {
    printf("Input %i, not even, replaced by %i\n", size, size + 1);
    size++;
}

Mat out = -1 * Mat::ones(size + 2, size + 2, CV_8S);
Mat center = Mat(out, Rect(1, 1, size, size));
center = Mat::ones(size, size, CV_8S);

return out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might already be handled by the `cv::copyMakeBorder` method.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat generate_kernel(int size, int outer_size=1)
{
    if (size % 2 == 0)
    {
        printf("Input %i, not even, replaced by %i\n", size, size + 1);
        size++;

    }
    Mat out = Mat::ones(size, size, CV_8S);
    copyMakeBorder(out,
                   out,
                   outer_size, // top
                   outer_size, // bottom
                   outer_size, // left
                   outer_size, // right
                   BORDER_CONSTANT,
                   Scalar(-1.0));
    return out;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    cout << "Size 1: " << generate_kernel(1) << endl;
    cout << "Size 3: " << generate_kernel(3) << endl;
    cout << "Size 5: " << generate_kernel(5) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Which would generate the following....

```
Size 1: [ -1,  -1,  -1;
          -1,   1,  -1;
          -1,  -1,  -1]

Size 3: [ -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1;
          -1,   1,   1,   1,  -1;
          -1,   1,   1,   1,  -1;
          -1,   1,   1,   1,  -1;
          -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1]

Size 5: [ -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1;
          -1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,  -1;
          -1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,  -1;
          -1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,  -1;
          -1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,  -1;
          -1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,  -1;
          -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1,  -1]
```